# Bottle Program in Python

Tags: python

I'm doing the Bottle Program in Python online as a practice exercise and I've managed to complete the exercise although I'm stuck on one last step which is the countdown for the rest of the song.

For example: If I enter '4' it only displays: (4 green bottles, hanging on the wall 4 green bottles hanging on the wall
And if one green bottle, should accidentally fall
There'd be 3 green bottles, hanging on the wall)

But I'm trying to work out how I can make it so it will go down like 3, 2, 1 and then finish.

If I was to enter in '7' then it would go from 7 down to 1.

I'm stuck on where I would need to include this within my program.

```
def bottles(b)
    print(b,"green bottles, hanging on the wall",   
          b,"green bottles hanging on the wall")

bottleno = int(input("Enter number of bottles: "))
bottles(bottleno)
print("And if one green bottle, should accidentally fall")
print("There'd be", bottleno-1, "green bottles, hanging on the wall")
```

Comment: A task repeated until a certain stop condition: whenever you see cases like that, think of loops. Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: As told in your previous question, please look into loops.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your forgot a `:` on your first line.

What you need to do is have a while loop in your function and put the repeating print statements in it like this:

```
def bottles(b):
  i = b
  while (i > 0):

    print(i,"green bottles, hanging on the wall",   
    i,"green bottles hanging on the wall")

    print("And if one green bottle, should accidentally fall")
    print("There'd be", i-1, "green bottles, hanging on the wall")

    i -= 1


bottleno = int(input("Enter number of bottles: "))
bottles(bottleno)
```